# Assign new value to every unique number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am new to SQL Server and trying to do some operations

Sample data:

```
Amount | BillID
-------+-------
 500   | 10009
 500   |  1492
 350   | 15892
 222   | 15596
 899   | 20566
 350   |  9566
```

How can I create a new column that holds a serial number according to the `Amount` column so the output looks like:

```
Amount | BillID | unique
-------+--------+-------
 500   |  10009 |   1
 500   |   1492 |   1
 350   |  15892 |   2
 222   |  15596 |   3
 899   |  20566 |   4
 350   |   9566 |   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over(order by amount) rn
from mytable t
```

This assigns a unique, incremental number to each `amount`. The smallest amount gets ranks `1`, and the number are assigned incrementally by increasing `amount`. This is not exactly the output you showed (where there is no apparent logic to order the ranks), but I think that's the logic you want in essence.